# Buiild:failed compileSDKVersion is not specified (minSdkVersion 16 ; compileSdkVersion 29)

Tags: react-native

I have this problem in my react native project. I'm getting the following warning in android studio:

> compileSDKVersion is not specified

This my build.gradle:

This happened after done unlink and uninstall in image-picker

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29`enter code here`
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```